# Linked library not found at run-time (c++)

Tags: c++, dll, linker

I have the following makefile

```
FLAGS = -g -c -Wall -Wextra -O2 -pedantic -Werror
CC = g++
SOURCE = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
INTERM = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCE))
OBJECTS = $(patsubst src/%,nbobj/%,$(INTERM))
RES = app
INCLUDE = -I../../libs
OPENCV = -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
LINK =  -L./../../libs -lgstd  $(OPENCV)


$(RES): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(RES) $(LINK)

nbobj/%.o: src/%.cpp 
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ -c $<

clean:
    rm -rf $(RES) $(OBJECTS)
```

It compiles fine, but when I run the program I get

error while loading shared libraries: libgstd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This raises a couple of questions for me:

- libgstd was clearly found at compile time (If I remove the -lgstd, the program does not compile), and the .so did not move when I ran the program. How is it suddenly no longer found?
- I have read lots of posts which say I need to modify the ld.conf. I thought the point of the -L flag was to precisely avoid that. I don't really want to modify a systems file for a small library that I wrote. Also I want to ship the executable and libgstd together in one folder, without forcing anyone to "install" libgstd by messing with systems files
- I have also read that the -R flag is the equivalent of -L for run-time, but if I compile with -R, the compiler says "error: unrecognized option ‘-R’"

Furthermore, I am running into a similar problem where I have a library that contains a call to "clock_gettime". It compiles fine but at runtime, when I use a function from that library, I get "undefined reference to `clock_gettime'". How is it that when I compiled the library, the linker apparently found clock_gettime, but then when I used the library it couldn't be found, even though no files had been moved?

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What does the -L flag do if not tell the linker to search in the directory and why does is there a difference between compilitime and runtime in terms of finding the library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While starting your program, the os can't find the lib to load, especially it doesn't even know where to search, since ./../../libs is not a path where it will search. You can do 2 things. first, move the lib to a folder it will search (depending on your system)

> /lib/ or /lib64/ or /usr/lib or ...

or second show your os where to search

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/absolut/path/to/libs

The parameter **-L** specifies additional paths where to search at link-time to the linker; **NOT** while runtime to the os. **-l** specifies additional libraries for the linker.